# Has Trump indicated who he will endorse if he remains disqualified from the ballot?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

Trump is currently disqualified from the ballot in [Colorado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trump_v._Anderson), and the case is being appealed to the Supreme Court.

Assuming the Supreme Court rules against Trump and he remains disqualified, has he indicated who he will endorse instead?

Comment: Being disqualified from the ballot in Colorado, or a few other states, doesn't mean he can't become President.

Comment: @DJClayworth: IIRC, SCOTUS has pretty much tipped its hand (based on the Qs they asked) on how they'll probably decide that, i.e. not allow a single state/district judge to disqualify a candidate for the whole US.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat Oral argument is suggestive of how the U.S. Supreme Court will rule, but not determinative. It isn't over until its over. Many grounds were suggested for overturning the Colorado Supreme Court's holding, but there was not a real consensus on any one of them. Complicating the situation is the fact that a GOP primary ballot with Trump on it has been mailed to Colorado Republican and unaffiliated voters already, although a ruling form SCOTUS could require a do over if it affirmed the Colorado Supreme Court. But if SCOTUS affirms, Trump will be disqualified everywhere.

Comment: This would be very out of character for trump to do until he knows for sure he's disqualified.

Comment: It makes no sense for Trump to pick an alternate now. Firstly, he'll want to extract as much as he can from each candidate before he names them (whether it's policy or promises of full pardons). Second, he'll want to pick a winner, and so he'll wait and see who's winning. Third, (as others have mentioend) he doesn't want to show weakness or any possibility of being disqualified. All this may impact on fundraising and reduce the money he gets; it may decrease the amount of publicity, media time, and adoring audiences he gets; and it will reduce his freedom to act however he likes.

Comment: @ohwilleke: and now it's over https://www.bbc.com/news/live/world-us-canada-68470315  'While the decision itself is not a surprise, [...] the court "not only resolved that the states can't [enforce Section 3], but they made it effectively impossible for anyone to implement Section 3 on the federal level"'

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat A most unfortunate and ill-reasoned decision, but courts do that sometimes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, and generally politicians don't do that unless they are effectively making a soft concession.  Usually politicians claim that they are running to win and if they start talking about what they will do if they lose, that's pretty much their way of admitting that they probably will lose.

Politicians' job is to energize the voters to get behind their vision of the future.  Asking what they'll do if the voters are not with them effectively attempts to force such politicians to paint the picture of the future in which they are irrelevant.